# Textbox shrinks when window dragging with arrow icon

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, window

I want to drag my window with arrow icon from right side bottom corner and its working fine, but controls in that window like TextBox shrinking fully like it's disappearing, so any one help how can i solve my problem.

Comment: What are you using for a Container Control. i.e. Grid, Canvas, dockpanel,stackpanel ?

Comment: I'm using Grid is it work for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using a [`ViewBox Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) to handle the scaling of your `Form`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100">
    <Grid  >
        <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both" >
            <!-- Your Form Data Enclosed Here -->
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: i tried it but it giving me controls in bigger in size but shrinking is working

Comment: @nag This was just an example, try showing an example of what your form looks like

Comment: @nag I will look at when I get back to my computer later today

Comment: @nag It looks like your pastbin expired or you removed it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9166/discussion-between-mark-hall-and-nag)

Comment: sorry mark i set up time for expiration, you can check this link http://pastebin.com/WdZgy5cC Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **MinWidth** to your controls.